# Javascript Canvas get color with getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, colors

When I cogo a color getImageData ( x, y, 1 , 1) .data in the pc gives me a rgb, but when I do it on the phone I have different values, eg :

pc: 255 255 255
Mobile : 255 254 255

Pc: 255 0 0
mobile: 255 2 0

Use colors to make certain decisions

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how i get the same color in the phone and the pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your difference occurs when drawing images to the canvas because drawings using the path commands should provide true rgba renderings across devices.

Browsers are allowed flexibility in how they apply color & gamma corrections to images drawn on the canvas so your `getImageData` values might be slightly different.

@KenFyrstenberg has created a nice script that reads the raw .png file and gives you their original color values direct from the file. Perhaps you could use his script to create a backing store (bitmap or array) that your can use to normalize user-selected pixel values across browsers.

https://github.com/epistemex/pngtoy